# Expecting ; at end of string declaration

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, declaration

What is wrong syntactically with these character arrays?

```
struct NewBuiltIn{
    char *CommandName[64] = "bigbluetest";
    char *FunctionName[64] = "big_blue_test";
    char *AnalyzerFunction[64] = "bbt_analyzer";
};
```

I get error code...

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        char *CommandName[64] = "bigbluetest";
                             ^
                             ;
```

Comment: ` char *CommandName[64] = "bigbluetest";` <- you're assigning a string ~ a pointer to an array of characters,  to an array of pointers to  characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initalize a struct at the time you are defining it. So you should define it proper, then create an *instance* of it.

```
struct NewBuiltIn my_builtin = {
    "bigbluetest",
    "big_blue_test",
    "bbt_analyzer"
};
```

So to define the struct, you can do it like this:

```
struct NewBuiltIn {
    char CommandName[64];
    char FunctionName[64];
    char AnalyzerFunction[64];
};
```

Which defines a `struct NewBultIn` with 3 members, all of which are char arrays. Your definition was creating an array of `char *` pointers.

Comment: And perhaps the struct field types are wrong as well? Should be `char` arrays or just `char *` rather than `char *` arrays.

Comment: You might want to explain how to properly define the struct as well. Seems that OP is trying to create an array of char, but defines it as an array of char *s